# Deallocating an array of pointers to objects?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

Consider the following situation:

```
Class** array = new Class*[8];
array[1] = new Class(1,2);
```

Is just doing "`delete[ ] array`" sufficient or should I precede the former with "`delete array[1]`". I am not completely comfortable with memory management.

Comment: Is it a valid code? I never saw the usage of the keyword "Class" in this manner.

Comment: @prabhakaran:  `Class` is not a keyword; `class` is.  Names are case sensitive in C++.

Comment: (though technically `class` isn't a name, it's a keyword... *sigh*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time you call `new[]`, you have to call `delete[]` on the pointer to deallocate. Every time you call `new`, you have to call `delete`.

In your case, you call `new` twice. `array[1]` contains a pointer to a class allocated with `new`, so it must be deallocated with `delete`. And `array` is a pointer to an array allocated with `new[]`, so it must be freed with `delete[]`.

Of course, you could have saved yourself this headache by simple declaring the array like this:

```
Class array[8];
array[1] = Class(1,2);
```

no dynamic memory allocation means no need to call `delete`.

Or using `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Class> array(8);
array[1] = Class(1,2);
```

Comment: Makes sense. I was thinking that since only the reference to the array was available in stack, deleting this reference should be sufficient, that is, delete[ ] array.

Comment: Consider that the first `new` creates an array containing 8 pointers. If the system was to automatically delete the individual pointers, how would it know *which ones* of them to delete? You've only set the second entry (`array[1]`) to point to another allocation. The remaining 7 entries in the array are uninitialized. How would the runtime know that 7 of them should *not* have `delete` called on them, but one should?

Comment: Thanks a lot jalf. I just have to remember that its like an xml element. every start tag should have its end tag. :)

Comment: Plus, how should it know whether to call `delete` or `delete[]` on them? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you create `vector` of objects of class *Class* and suppose `sizeof(Class)` is more than 4 bytes, then `vector` is going to make copies and it will waste memory. Instead consider using vector of pointers to Class objects, which will always create `4 * 8 = 32` bytes of memory irrelevant of the `sizeof(Class)`.

Comment: If you want to deallocate in your scenario, do this: 

for (i = 0 to 7) {delete array[i];} delete array;